# Inserting some rows with SqLite (Java Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

im trying to insert multiple rows in my database (Sqlite), but, for example, when i get an object with 5 rows, and trying to insert into my db, it just insert 3 rows, so 2 of them skips.

I did some logs, and i'm getting this 5 rows, but just inserting 3.

(Sorry my bad english)

```
for (DocumentLiniaAutoventa dla : document.linies){

                ContentValues valueslinies = new ContentValues();
                valueslinies.put("empresa", dla.empresa);
                valueslinies.put("tipusdocument", document.tipusdocument);
                valueslinies.put("any", dla.any);
                valueslinies.put("serie", dla.serie);
                valueslinies.put("numero", dla.numero);
                valueslinies.put("linia", dla.linia);
                valueslinies.put("tipus", dla.tipus);
                valueslinies.put("codiarticle", dla.codiarticle);
                valueslinies.put("codiarticlepack", dla.codiarticlepack);
                valueslinies.put("unitats", dla.unitats);
                valueslinies.put("caixes", dla.caixes);
                valueslinies.put("preu", dla.preu);
                valueslinies.put("descompte1", dla.descompte1);
                valueslinies.put("descompte2", dla.descompte2);
                valueslinies.put("descompte3", dla.descompte3);
                valueslinies.put("descomptelinia", dla.descomptelinia);
                valueslinies.put("iva", dla.iva);
                valueslinies.put("recarrec", dla.recarrec);
                valueslinies.put("import", dla.importe);
                valueslinies.put("abono", dla.abono);
                valueslinies.put("unidadescaja", dla.unidadescaja);
                db.insert(DATA_MANAGER_LINIESDOCUMENT, null, valueslinies);}
```

Comment: the return code from `insert()` returns the rowId (or -1 if an error occurs). you should check that. you might also try `insertOrThrow()` to catch any exceptions that might be occurring

Comment: I will check it and ask when i can. Thanks.